# Поиск минимума в массиве, его использование, а если не подходит, то поиск следующего минимума

Tags: javascript, массивы

Вообщем, трабл в том, что у меня есть массив

```
var arr = [{
    val: 6.46,
    mode: "day"
  },
  {
    val: 5.38,
    mode: "day"
  },
  {
    val: 6.99,
    mode: "day"
  },
  {
    val: 5.41,
    mode: "day"
}]
```

Я хочу найти минимальный val в этом массиве, использовать его, а если не подходит по условию, то взять следующий минимальный val из этого массива.
Саму функцию поиска минимума сделать то сделал:

```
function arr_dayMin(min) {  
    return min.reduceRight(function (p, v) {
        return ( p.val < v.val ? p : v );
    });
}
```

А вот сделать так, чтобы когда нашел первый минимум проверить его по условию, и если он не подходит, то взять следующий минимум не получается.
Как я понимаю нужно это делать через цикл, но как именно ума не приложу, может кто поможет?

Comment: можешь, например, отсортировать массив и идти по нему в цикле

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду сразу расставить все подмассивы в порядке от меньшего val до большего?

Comment: да_____________

Comment: Если второй минимум будет последним, то достаточно запомнить только минимум и второй минимум  и ничего не сортировать.

Comment: возможно условию удовлетворит только самый больший val, но мне нужно все до него проверить, поэтому я думаю с сортировкой это как раз то, что нужно.

Answer (score -1):

```
function arr_dayMin(min) {  
    return min.reduceRight(function (p, v) {
        if(condition) return ( p.val < v.val ? p : v );
    });
}
```

Comment: этот код будет возвращать минимум по условию, а мне нужно каждый val на условие проверить, начиная с самого малого и если он не удовлетворяет ему, то следующий, а если и он не подходит, то следующий после него и т. д.

Comment: Тогда я не понял, чего вы хотите. Вам нужно найти минимальный элемент, проверить его условием, и если условие ложное, то идти к следующему? Тогда для начала нужно отсортировать массив по val и с конца проверять функцией, что написана в моем ответе. Все проверять не обязательно, достаточно найти минимальное, которое удовлетворяет условию